# how could i integrate via me social site into iphone app

Tags: xcode, ios6, oauth, social-networking

hi i want to integrate **Via Me** social site into my iphone app,i googled but didn't find any samples.

Comment: I'd start with http://via.me/developers

Comment: Rob,can you send me the any sample what you did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic process is as follows:

1. Create a [custom URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) for your app. Via Me will use this after the user has been authenticated, to return to your app. In my example, I created one called "`robviame://`"
2. Register your app at http://via.me/developers. This will give you a client id and a client secret:

   [image: register app at via.me]
3. When you want to authenticate the user, you call:

   ```
   NSString *redirectUri = [[self redirectURI] stringByAddingPercentEscapesForURLParameterUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.via.me/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code", kClientID, redirectUri];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
   ```
4. What that will do is fire up your web browser and give the user a chance to log on and grant permissions to your app. When user finishes that process, because you've defined your custom URL scheme, it will call the following method in your app delegate:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
   {
       // do whatever you want here to parse the code provided back to the app
   }
   ```

   for example, I'll call a handler for my Via Me response:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
   {
       ViaMeManager *viaMeManager = [ViaMeManager sharedManager];

       if ([[url host] isEqualToString:viaMeManager.host])
       {
           [viaMeManager handleViaMeResponse:[self parseQueryString:[url query]]];

           return YES;
       }

       return NO;
   }

   // convert the query string into a dictionary

   - (NSDictionary *)parseQueryString:(NSString *)query
   {
       NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       NSArray *queryParameters = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

       for (NSString *queryParameter in queryParameters) {
           NSArray *elements = [queryParameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
           NSString *key     = [elements[0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           NSString *value   = [elements[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
           value             = [[value componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

           [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
       }
       return dictionary;
   }
   ```

   That handler might, for example, save the code and then request the access token:

   ```
   - (void)handleViaMeResponse:(NSDictionary *)parameters
   {
       self.code = parameters[@"code"];

       if (self.code)
       {
           // save the code

           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.code forKey:kViaMeUserDefaultKeyCode];
           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

           // now let's authenticate the user and get an access key

           [self requestToken];
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: parameters = %@", __FUNCTION__, parameters);

           NSString *errorCode = parameters[@"error"];
           if ([errorCode isEqualToString:@"access_denied"])
           {
               [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                           message:@"Via Me functions will not be enabled because you did not authorize this app"
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
           }
           else
           {
               [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                           message:@"Unknown Via Me authorization error"
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   and the code to retrieve the token might look like:

   ```
   - (void)requestToken
   {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.via.me/oauth/access_token"];
       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

       NSDictionary *paramsDictionary = @{@"client_id"     : kClientID,
                                          @"client_secret" : kClientSecret,
                                          @"grant_type"    : @"authorization_code",
                                          @"redirect_uri"  : [self redirectURI],
                                          @"code"          : self.code,
                                          @"response_type" : @"token"
                                          };

       NSMutableArray *paramsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
       [paramsDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
           [paramsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [obj stringByAddingPercentEscapesForURLParameterUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
       }];

       NSData *paramsData = [[paramsArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       [request setHTTPBody:paramsData];

       NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
           if (error)
           {
               NSLog(@"%s: NSURLConnection error = %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
               return;
           }

           NSError *parseError;
           id results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

           if (parseError)
           {
               NSLog(@"%s: NSJSONSerialization error = %@", __FUNCTION__, parseError);
               return;
           }

           self.accessToken = results[@"access_token"];

           if (self.accessToken)
           {
               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.accessToken forKey:kViaMeUserDefaultKeyAccessToken];
               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
           }
       }];
   }
   ```

Hopefully this will be enough to get you going. This is described in greater detail at the http://via.me/developers page.

Comment: thanks for giving reply,i got problem in redirectURI how can i get that URI and what is the type of ViaMeManager as you mentioned in the code.

Comment: @KishoreBhamidipati I wasn't trying to provide a full example, but rather just illustrate the concepts. But if you want a more complete code sample, see https://github.com/robertmryan/via-me-demonstration. You still need to register your app, configure your custom scheme, and integrate the client id/secret keys, but at least this code sample will help illuminate some of my other utility methods that the above code snippets take advantage of.

Comment: Hi Rob, How did you crate the robviame:// custom URL Scheme, can u please provide me where to register this link. I did not find any link      on the step1. can u please guide me. thanks in Advance  @Rob

Comment: @Babul You define your custom URL just by making a few settings in the app's plist. I provided a link to Apple's documentation on this topic in my answer (see the "Implementing Custom URL Schemes" discussion there). Alternatively, see [this article](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) for a discussion better supported with screen snapshots. Once you have your custom URL scheme defined, you can then specify that in the "redirect URI" in the app registration page on via.me's developer portal.

Comment: @rob authorization was success and image posted successfully,but posted image was not appeared in the via.me site.Here i logged using the facebook account so image was appeared in facebook site,how could i get the image into via.me site?

Comment: @KishoreBhamidipati I'm surprised by that, because it showed up for me. It took 20-30 seconds, but it appeared. I might suggest examining the `results` dictionary generated in `uploadData` and see if you see anything curious there. When I post, I get a nice little inventory about the image I just shared. Also, make sure you're logging on under the same userid/password that you used when authenticating the app.

Comment: ok fine image appeared in via.me. But image was appeared in both facebook and via.me site.I want to appear in via.me site only is it possible?@rob

Comment: I doubt it. You obviously can revoke its permissions via the FB settings (under apps), but I don't think you can do that via the Via Me API. It looks like that's a fundamental design of Via Me, that it shares with one or other of those existing social networks.